# Fail to unlock terraform state due to version not matching

Tags: terraform, locking, workspace

I'm trying to unlock a terraform state with the command

```
terraform force-unlock <id>
```

but I'm getting

```
Failed to load state: Remote workspace Terraform version "1.4.5" does not match local Terraform version "1.5.6"
```

I tried increase version in main.tf then `terraform init -upgrade` but it only updates local setup

then I downloaded the closest version still availaible 1.4.6 but I'm getting

```
Failed to load state: Remote workspace Terraform version "1.4.5" does not match local Terraform version "1.4.6"
```

Finally checking the state file doesn't show a lock property in clear (stored on Artifactory). Restoring the previous state (serial 65) strangely didn't helped.

```
{"data":{"type":"state-versions","attributes":{"serial":66,"force":false,"md5":"...","lineage":"...","state":"..."","json-state-outputs":"e30="},"relationships":null}}
```

Note: `terraform apply -lock=false` do work even with local version 1.5.6

How can I either remove the lock or upgrade the remote state to get the unlock-command working? Does the state or lock is cached on the local setup?

Comment: You can find all the terraform versions here: https://releases.hashicorp.com/terraform/. Also, you cannot just switch back to the previous value of `"serial"`, if I recall correctly you have to workout how to fix the lineage as well.

Comment: Thanks, I miss that page. I finally fixed the issue by editing the workspace file.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking at the wrong place. The lock is inside the file `workspace.json`

```
{"data":{"attributes":{"actions":null,"description":null,"environment":null,"locked":true,
```

Changing the locked value to false fix the issue.

Nonetheless if anyone know how to force the upgrade of the remote state to fix the issue, it would be appreciated because even while passing command in 1.5.6, workspace files remains in 1.4.6.